# simple jquery dropdown - clearTimeout, setTimeout issues

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, settimeout

HTML:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="#"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Three</span></a></li>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
var timeout = null;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.topnav li").mouseover(function() {

        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);

        $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show();

    }).mouseout(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(closemenu, 500);
    });

    // sub menu mouseovers keep dropdown open
    $("ul.subnav li").mouseover(function() {
        if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    ).mouseout(function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(closemenu, 500);
        // alert(timeout);

    });

    // any click closes
    $(document).click(closemenu);
});

// Closes all open menus 
function closemenu() {
    $('ul.subnav:visible').hide();
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

I'm having issues with timeout. In use, if i mouseover "Three", the dropdown stays out forever. if i mouseover "A", dropdown will stay out forever, but if I mouseover "B" or anything lower, the menu will close on me.  if you uncomment "// alert(timeout);" it gets there for B, (and A) but timeout will have a value.  why is this?  i thought clearTimeout would null the timeout variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify your code overall by using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul.topnav li").hover(function() {
    var timeout = $(this).data("timeout");
    if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast');
  }, function() {
      $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).find("ul.subnav").slideUp();
      }, this), 500));
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
      $('ul.subnav:visible').hide();
  });
});​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rAHyF/)

Instead of sharing a global `timeout` variable, this sets a timeout *per* top level `<li>`, each one has an independent timer, and when you hover back over that element, only *its timer* is cleared.  Also [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) uses [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), rather than [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/), the difference is when you go into a child or between children, `mouseenter` doesn't fire again, and `mouseleave` doesn't fire on the parent `<li>` we care about.

You can test this with the demo link above, I added sub-items to the first menu as well, to demonstrate they're independent.  If you happen to have question about the [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) in there, it's just making `this` inside that timeout anonymous function refer to what I want it to (the current `this`)...the element that needs closing after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

youre trying to build a drop down menu? why not use existing jquery plugins for that or better yet, css-only drop down menu like http://purecssmenu.com/?

Comment: i'm trying to work it into an existing website menu, so i was trying to go the simplest route possible