# CSS drop down offset from link?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Hi, I'm doing a drop down menu in HTML/CSS the normal way; i.e., using `ul li` and nested `ul`s for the drop-down menus.

I want to have the drop down menu slightly offset below the nav bar like it is here in 
[Orman Clark's Studeo Theme](http://themes.premiumpixels.com/studeo/). I can't work out how to do this and still keep the drop down menu visible when I move my cursor between the top link and the drop down menu.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.setTimeout()` is the key you need!

(Try to hover on the 3rd li and reach the open menu by moving around the page! It will stay open, waiting for a predefined amount of time for you to mouse over. If it does not receive that input in that period, it will hide itself again.)

This could help:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/rAHyF/275/)

Answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316213/simple-jquery-dropdown-cleartimeout-settimeout-issues)